# ASIHTTPRequest Resumes download even after killing the application

Tags: ios

How do you pause a download and resume it?

How you cancel a download?

I'm using downloadRequest.allowResumeForFileDownloads = YES; This makes the app to resume download even after I kill the application.

Normal cancel and normal pause and resume works if I use this. But the only problem is mentioned above.

Thanks guys.

Comment: if you got answer then please share.

Answer (score 0):

`[request cancel];` should do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand the question then. Do you want it to resume or not?

Comment: yes i want the download to resume. it works when you add the following,
downloadRequest.allowResumeForFileDownloads = YES; 
But when i use the above line, even if I kill the app and run it again, the download starts exactly from where it paused last time.